# Neural network with sigmoid function always get value closer to 0.5 fo XOR

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, sigmoid

I am practicing with neural network from scratch to handle XOR problem. However, the neural network output always getting close to 0.5 no matter what input it received.

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

def generate_XOR_easy():

inputs = []
labels = []

for i in range(11):
    hasil = [round(0.1*i, 1), round(0.1*i, 1)]
    inputs.append(hasil)
    labels.append(0)

    if 0.1*i == 0.5:
        continue

    hasil2 = [round(0.1*i,1), round(1-0.1*i, 1)]
    inputs.append(hasil2)
    labels.append(1)
    return np.array(inputs), np.array(labels).reshape(21,1)

def sigmoid(x):
   return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-x))

def deriv_sig(x):
   return np.multiply(x, 1.0-x)

epochs = 1000
n_input = 2
hidden_one = 3
hidden_two = 3
n_output = 1
learning_rate = 0.001

np.random.seed(10)

weigth_one = np.random.rand(n_input, hidden_one)
weight_two = np.random.rand(hidden_one, hidden_two)
weight_three = np.random.rand(hidden_two, n_output)

xor_data = generate_XOR_easy()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xor_data[0], xor_data[1], 
test_size=0.2, random_state=4)


for epoch in range(epochs):
    
   #feedforward
   input_to_h1 = np.dot(x_train, weigth_one)
   output_h1 = sigmoid(input_to_h1)

   input_to_h2 = np.dot(output_h1, weight_two)
   output_h2 = sigmoid(input_to_h2)

   input_to_output = np.dot(output_h2, weight_three)
   output_output = sigmoid(input_to_output)

   #backpropagation

    error = output_output - y_train

    error_2_1 = error * deriv_sig(output_output)
    error_1_w3 = np.dot(output_h2.T, error_2_1)

    w3_error1 = np.dot(error_2_1, weight_three.T)
    h2_front = w3_error1 * deriv_sig(output_h2)
    h2Back_w2 = np.dot(output_h1.T, h2_front)

    h2Back_h1front = np.dot(h2_front, weight_two.T)
    h1front_h1back = h2Back_h1front * deriv_sig(output_h1)
    h1back_w1 = np.dot(x_train.T, h1front_h1back)

    weight_three -= learning_rate * error_1_w3
    weight_two -= learning_rate * h2Back_w2
    weigth_one -= learning_rate * h1back_w1
```

When I print the output every iteration, the result will go closer to 0.5 (for all input).
The code is very messy since I am still new and need more practice with machine learning and deep learning code. Is there anyone know whats wrong? I really appreciate any help and suggestion.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem by myself and actually it is very simple. I got good result after I increase the learning rate and number of iteration. I hope my problem and solution might help other who got the same problem.